# Avoid repeating code in Form class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a form class that looks like this:

```
class UserForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name, :phone_number,:address1, :address2

  validates :name, presence: true

  def create_user
    User.create! do |u|
      u.name = name
      u.phone_number = phone_number
      u.address1 = address1
      u.address2 = address2
    end
  end

  def update_user(user)
    user.name = name
    user.phone_number = phone_number
    user.address1 = address1
    user.address2 = address2

    user.save 
  end
end
```

I have created as many attr_accessor as instance variables this instance has when I initialized with a hash like `UserForm.new({name: 'x', phone_number: 'z'})`.

How can I avoid repeating code from the create and update? I have much more attributes for a User, and I am trying to avoid repeating all those attributes in both create and update.

Comment: You can combine the 2 methods into one, and use the `find_or_create_by` ?

Answer (score 2):

**By doing it the Rails way instead.**

I would say that what you are doing is most likely unnecessary. In Rails controllers pass input to models - and models handle validating that input. [Form builders](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) handle binding model attributes and errors to html.

So "Form Classes" do not really figure in at all as they would in other frameworks such as Symfony 2. In fact you may just be adding another level of duplication and indirection rather than DRYing your application out.

There is no need to bind attributes 1-1 when creating model instances in rails. Rails model initializers and factory methods take a hash of attributes:

```
User.new(name: "Max", awesome: true) 
User.create(name: "Max", awesome: true) # this is just .new and .save
```

The Rails way is to setup your form inputs so that they line up with model attributes:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
   <%= f.label :name %>
   <%= f.text_input :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <%= f.label :awesome %>
   <%= f.check_box :awesome %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller you would simply whitelist and pass the params to the model initializer:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] 

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private 

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :awesome)
    end
end
```

If what you want is to DRY out you controller you can use [responders](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html) and filters. If you need to share methods you would use concerns or classical inheritance.

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  respond_with(@user)
end
```

To reuse forms and form components you would use [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

```
# app/views/users/new.html.erb
<h1>Create a new user</h1>
<% render partial: 'form' %>

# app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<h1>Editing <%= @user.name %></h1>
<% render partial: 'form' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that exposes the instance variables as a hash...

```
class UserForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name, :phone_number,:address1, :address2

  validates :name, presence: true

  def attrs
    (instance_variables.map{|i| [i.to_s[1..-1].to_sym, instance_variable_get(i)]}).to_h
  end

  def create_user
    User.create!(attrs) 
  end

  def update_user(user)
    user.update_attributes(attrs)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how could have the attr_accessors to use the attrs, instead of having :name, :phone_number...

Comment: the `attrs` are derived from the `attr_accessor` so `attr_accessor` is the chicken, `attrs` is the egg. You need to list them somewhere...

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. We are not using attrs within attr_accessor. That's why we use instance_variables, that is the egg right?

Comment: Attrs is a method we wrote for this question. It changes instance variables into an attribute hash.